# Unknown LAN textbook title

Tags: networking, local-area-network, ethernet

I am preparing for my computer networks exam and I stumbled upon [this textbook excerpt](http://www.sce.carleton.ca/faculty/lambadaris/courses/521/supplementary/token.pdf). I cannot find this book in google, I don't know the author or the title. Do any of you recognize this book?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic.

Answer (score 4):

Google Books finds ["Communication networks:
a first course"](http://books.google.com/books?id=Yf9SAAAAMAAJ&q=5.3+%22token+ring+networks%22&dq=5.3+%22token+ring+networks%22&hl=en&ei=9QvzTeaYG46atwfTv6zsBg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAQ) by Jean Walrand.